# Trying to get a JSONPath array of all leaves on json object

Tags: go, jsonpath

New to Go.  My first project is to compare a NodeJS proxy and a Go proxy for account number tokenization.  I have been doing NodeJS for a few years and am very comfortable with it.  My proxies will not know the format of any request or response from the target servers.  But it does have configurations coming from Redis/MongoDB that is similar to JSONPath expression.  These configurations can change things like the target server/path, query parameters, headers, request body and response body.

For NodeJS, I am using deepdash's paths function to get an array of all the leaves in a JSON object in JSONPath format.  I am using this array and RegEx to find my matching paths that I need to process from any request or response body.  So far, it looks like I will be using gjson for my JSONPath needs, but it does not have anything for the paths command I was using in deepdash.

Will I need to create a recursive function to build this JSONPath array myself, or does anyone know of a library that will produce something similar?

for example:

```
{
  "response": {
    "results": [
      {
        "acctNum": 1234,
        "someData": "something"
      },
      {
        "acctNum": 5678,
        "someData": "something2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I will get an array back in the format:

```
[
  "response.results[0].acctNum",
  "response.results[0].someData",
  "response.results[1].acctNum",
  "response.results[1].someData"
]
```

and I can then use my filter of `response.results[*].acctNum` which translates to `response\.results\[.*\]\.acctNum` in Regex to get my acctNum fields.

From this filtered array, I should be able to use gjson to get the actual value, process it and then set the new value (I am using lodash in NodeJS)

Comment: Was the answer helpful in some way?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of JSONPath implementations in GoLang. And I cannot really give a recommendation in this respect.

However, I think all you need is this basic path: `$..*`

It should return in pretty much any implementation that is able to return pathes instead of values:

```
[
   "$['response']",
   "$['response']['results']",
   "$['response']['results'][0]",
   "$['response']['results'][1]",
   "$['response']['results'][0]['acctNum']",
   "$['response']['results'][0]['someData']",
   "$['response']['results'][1]['acctNum']",
   "$['response']['results'][1]['someData']"
]
```

If I understand correctly this should still work using your approach filtering using RegEx.

Go JSONPath implementations:

- http://github.com/PaesslerAG/jsonpath
- http://github.com/bhmj/jsonslice
- http://github.com/ohler55/ojg
- http://github.com/oliveagle/jsonpath
- http://github.com/spyzhov/ajson
- http://github.com/vmware-labs/yaml-jsonpath